# Image in ImageView doesn't display the same way as it looks in the xml preview

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview, shapes

The image is a 128x128 play icon.

Here is the layer list "play_layer"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_border" android:width="75dp" android:height="75dp" android:gravity="center"/>
<item android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp" android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/play_player"/>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

This image has a border around it. In the preview it looks like it's supposed to. [image]

Instead the image ends up like this:
[image]

Here is my ImageView

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="75dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/playerPlayButton"
     android:src="@drawable/play_layer"
     />
```

No matter what size I change, the play icon is still too large.

The circle_border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorBlackTransparent75"/>

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"
        android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

What am I missing? Is the image too big?(128x128) Surely the size should change to 25x25 like is specified in the bitmap inside the layer list.

Comment: Why use two images? use one instead.

Comment: The circle_border drawable isn't an image. It's a background & border for the play image. I would rather not combine them into one image if that's what you mean... it would be easier to keep this as a drawable shape.